# Upgraded Visual Studio project not using correct MSVCR DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I upgraded a Visual Studio 2013 project to Visual Studio 2015. The upgrade changed my Platfrom Toolset from v120 to v140, as expected. I can compile fine, but when I go to run I get:

The program can't start because MSVCR120D.dll is missing from your computer.

Yes, I very well realize that I can go and download the dll and stick it in the right folder and get it working. But that's treating the symptom, not the cause.

I'd rather figure out why the program is not using MSVCR140D. What else do I need to change to complete the upgrade?

Comment: Your program no doubt is using the VS2015 runtimes.  It is a library you link that doesn't.  You'll have to rebuild it.  The fact that it is a debug build instead of the release build could be a cue.  Fwiw, never try to deploy the debug build.

Comment: Yuuup, that was it. Good call. Thank you sir.